# /var/lib/systemd/coredump/ — what is it, and can I delete it?

Tags: systemd, disk-usage, manjaro, core-dump

I'm running Manjaro KDE and the `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` folder is around 500MB. What is it there for, and is it safe to delete it? `sudo systemctl status` shows running and no failed units.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/var/lib/systemd/coredump` is where [`systemd-coredump`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html) stores core dumps. You can list them with [`coredumpctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/coredumpctl.html).

If you don’t plan on investigating your core dumps any further, you can delete the contents of the directory.

Comment: Oh, okay. I had some coredump entries in `systemctl status` but I was able to resolve them without looking at the logs.

Comment: You can't delete those core files. They are owned by root.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet given the context of the question I think it’s a fair assumption that the user could become root if necessary.

Comment: deleting is temporary fix.  I keep getting huge chromium coredumps when chromium crashes.  If you are not doing dev work where you need coredumps then disable them with these instructions.  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-core-dumps-in-linux-with-systemd-sysctl/

Comment: @DKebler or you can configure `systemd-coredump`, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html#Disabling%20coredump%20processing

Comment: How can non-root users delete their core files?